# Sheet order autopopulate with VBA Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make the sheet number auto-population in Excel (preferably with VBA macro). It's not a standard sheet numeration, which starts from the very beginning of my workbook. The sheets I want to order begin near the end of the document. In the bottom right corner, they're identified like OT 1 of 5, which means that the "OT" sheet is first from 5 available.

[image]

The total number of the sheets is dependant on the number of flats defined in the "Frontsheet" and divided by 2 (I want to have 2 flats in one sheet).

Because My code includes also the sheets autupopulation for this flat number  analogically to the order numeration I would like to achieve it looks as follows:

```
 Sub otdr()

 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 Dim xNumber As Long, yNumber As Long
 Dim otdr As Range
 Dim xName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("OTDR TRACE - 1")
 Set otdr = ws.Range("Q46")  'the cell, where order of sheets is included
 xNumber = Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D32").Value  'the cell where number of flats is included
 yNumber = xNumber / 2   'dividing number of flats by 2

 For j = 1 To xlNumber
 otdr = "OT " & j & " of " & Number  ' ordering sheets
 Next

 For i = 1 To (xNumber / 2)
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "OTDR TRACE - " & (i + 1)  'autopopulating new sheets
 Next

 ws.Activate

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

The new sheets are added, but I am getting the wrong order. I have 3 sheets added and it's fine, but their final amount is 3, not 5. I don't know why the "0" comes instead of the proper number. What Have I done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution looks as follows:

```
 Sub otdr()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim xNumber As Long, yNumber As Long
 Dim otdr As Range
 Dim xName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("OTDR TRACE - 1")
 Set otdr = ws.Range("Q46")
 xNumber = Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D32").Value
 yNumber = xNumber / 2   'total amount of our sheets in the order

 For i = 1 To (xNumber / 2)
 otdr = "OT " & (i + 1) & " of " & (yNumber + 1)
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "OTDR TRACE - " & (i + 1)
 Next

 ws.Activate
 otdr = "OT 1 of " & (yNumber + 1)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

We don't need the `j` variable anymore. We can base everything on the existing `i` variable.

Next, we should keep everything in one loop, where before sheet population we should define the total amount of these sheets:

```
    otdr = "OT " & (i + 1) & " of " & (yNumber + 1)
```

However because the first sheet comes in the wrong order we can preventionally use again the

```
    otdr = "OT 1 of " & (yNumber + 1)
```

since our first sheet in the order has been activated after loop done.